# Cannot upgrade packages when adding melpa to the package-archives

Tags: gnutls, http, ssl

I have problems upgrading packages coming from melpa:

When executing `list-package` with `"https://melpa.org/packages/"` in the `package-archives` I get the following in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
Using a proxy for https...
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) Received alert:  Handshake failed
gnutls.el: (err=[-12] A TLS fatal alert has been received.) boot: (:priority NORMAL :hostname melpa.org :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits nil :trustfiles (/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt) :crlfiles nil :keylist nil :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
error in process filter: End of file during parsing
```

I guess this is an SSL/TLS issue, so I checked:

1. I had Emacs compile with the default gnutls support.
2. I have set `(setq package-check-signature nil)` before `(package-initialize)`

Does Emacs needs to know some certificates for melpa?

#### More environment info:

- Emacs is 27.1 compiled from source.
- OS is CentOS 6. (Cannot change the OS.)
- Connection is via a local proxy (which does not need any authentication).

Comment: Consider retrying without the proxy.

Comment: @wasamasa I have to use the proxy to connect the Internet, without I'm stuck in the company-wide Intranet..

Comment: Yes, so consider using that machine outside the company internet, like by disabling all VPN software and using a mobile hotspot.

Comment: @wasamasa Unfortunately I cannot connect the machine to another network due to security restrictions. I'm looking for an in-Emacs solution.

Comment: I'm suggesting you possible ideas for debugging. Failing to change the network settings you could attempt to reproduce the environment inside Docker or so. Another thing worth trying is to see whether you get the same error when browsing a HTTPS site in `M-x eww` to see if it's specific to MELPA or not.

Comment: Same problem here with similar env: CentOS6; emacs 26.2 from source. Not using proxy so this does not seem to be the cause. I would try to update emacs but not too much hope on that since you are already using 27.1. With ```(setq gnutls-log-level 5)``` I see a " Handshake failed - was received" message before the same message you reported - only difference is that my :min-prime-bits is 256

Comment: @wasamasa eww to https://wikipedia.org does not work, message is ```gnutls.c: [1] (Emacs) fatal error: The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.```.

Comment: Have also tried ```(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")``` but no success. Still working on solving it, will post any news.